# ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=4>

Tags: python

Consider the following program:

```
import tempfile
import unittest
import subprocess

def my_fn(f):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f)
    yield p.stdout.readline()
    p.kill()
    p.wait()

def my_test():
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
        l = list(my_fn(f))

class BuggyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_fn(self):
        my_test()

my_test()
unittest.main()
```

Running it results in the following output:

```
a.py:13: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=4>
  l = list(my_fn(f))
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

OK
```

What is the actual cause of the warning and how to fix it? Note that if I comment out `unittest.main()` the problem disappears, which means that it's specific to subprocess+unittest+tempfile.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563711/disabling-python-3-2-resourcewarning

Comment: @Leon but why does it even want me to silence the warnings? Does unittest disable file closing or something?

Comment: `unitttest` simply sets a higher warning level than usual. You can achieve the same effect by running python with the `-Wd` option. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html#updating-code-for-new-versions-of-python

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be closing the streams associated with the `Popen()` object you opened. For your example, that's the `Popen.stdout` stream, created because you instructed the `Popen()` object to create a pipe for the child process standard output. The easiest way to do this is by using the `Popen()` object as a context manager:

```
with subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f) as p:
    yield p.stdout.readline()
    p.kill()
```

I dropped the `p.wait()` call as `Popen.__exit__()` handles this for you, after having closed the handles.

If you want to further figure out exactly what cause the resource warning, then we can start by doing what the warning tells us, and [enable the `tracemalloc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) by setting the [`PYTHONTRACEMALLOC` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONTRACEMALLOC):

```
$ PYTHONTRACEMALLOC=1 python a.py
a.py:13: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=4>
  l = list(my_fn(f))
Object allocated at (most recent call last):
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", lineno 844
    self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.019s

OK
```

So the warning is thrown by a file opened by the `subprocess` module. I'm using Python 3.8.0 here, and so line 844 in the trace points to [these lines in `subprocess.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f90e0d2371bc2bcab7bf5307cfd73571eb06b375/Lib/subprocess.py#L843-L844):

```
if c2pread != -1:
    self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
```

`c2pread` is the file handle for one half of a [`os.pipe()` pipe object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe) created to handle communication from child process to Python parent process (created by the [`Popen._get_handles()` utility method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f90e0d2371bc2bcab7bf5307cfd73571eb06b375/Lib/subprocess.py#L1457-L1508), because you set `stdout=PIPE`). `io.open()` is exactly the same thing as the built-in [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). So this is where the `BufferedIOReader` instance is created, to act as a wrapper for a pipe to receive the output the child process produces.

You could also explicitly close `p.stdout`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f)
yield p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.close()
p.kill()
p.wait()
```

or use `p.stdout` as a context manager:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f)
with p.stdout:
    yield p.stdout.readline()
p.kill()
p.wait()
```

but it's easier to just *always* use `subprocess.Popen()` as a context manager, as it'll continue to work properly regardless of how many `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` pipes you created.

Note that most `subprocess` code examples don't do this, because they tend to use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), which closes the file handles for you.

Answer (score 1):

I also got some `ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=7 mode='wb' closefd=True>` messages when running unit tests. I couldn't use the `Popen` object as a context manager, so I did this in my classes `__del__` method:

```py
import subprocess

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child= subprocess.Popen(['dir'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    def __del__(self):
        self.child.terminate()
        self.child.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change `my_fn` to use `with`, then you won't need `kill` and `wait`.  Python'll close it for you:

```
def my_fn(f):
    with subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f) as p:
        yield p.stdout.readline()
```